# Explanation on characterstic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$A_2 = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        a & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$

So the characteristic polynomial of $A_2$ is $P_a(t) = (t-1)^2 - a  $

Then, $ P_a(t) = t^2 -2t +1 -a$

So the sqrt of $P_a(t)$ is $4-4(1-a) = 4a$ which means sqrt = $4a$.

Well, For some reason if $a > 0$ then $\Lambda_1 = 1 - \sqrt a$ and $\Lambda_2 = 1 + \sqrt a$

Can anyone explain why? (I did understand what happens when $a < 0$ and when $a = 0$)

Comment: I don't understand this part "So the sqrt of $P_a(t)$ is $4-4(1-a) = 4a$ which means sqrt = $4a$". The roots one gets with the quadratic formula are $1-\sqrt a$ and $1+\sqrt a$. If $a\ge 0$, there's nothing to say. If $a<0$, then $\sqrt a$ is either undefined or it is $i\sqrt {-a}$, depending on context.

Comment: But how? I didn't get it yet.

Comment: How what?${{}}$

Comment: In dependence of value $a$ you have or pure real or complex roots. The value of $a$ then determines the behavior of dynamical system $\dot x =A x$, in particular the property of stationary point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the *discriminant* of $P_a(t)$ is $4a$. The discriminant of $px^2+qx+r$ is indeed $\Delta=q^2-4pr$, which in your case simplifies to $4a$. The roots of that quadratic are
$$\frac{-q\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2p};$$
again, in your case, that means that the roots are
$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4a}}{2} = 1\pm\sqrt{a}.$$
If $a>0$, then you get $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ as in your post. If $a=0$ then the two roots are the same, both equal to $1$, and the matrix has only the single eigenvalue $1$. Finally, if $a<0$, then $1\pm\sqrt{a}$ is nonreal, and the matrix has no real eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you very much @rogerl

Answer (score 2):

The roots of the characteristic polynomial $P_a(t)=t^2-2t+1-a$ are 
$$t = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(1-a)}}{2}=1 \pm \sqrt{a}.$$
So these are the eigen values of $A_2$.

If $a>0$, then the roots are real, hence the eigen values are real.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the characteristic polynomial of your matrix $A_2$ is $t^2-2t+1-a$.

As you can see, this is a quadratic equation of second order of the form $dx^2+ex+f$. To get the solution of $dx^2+ex+f=0$, you should calculate the [discriminant of a quadtratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) which is given by $\Delta=e^2-4df$.

As you already did, the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is $\Delta=4a$. So the solution of the equation $t^2-2t+1-a=0$ depends on the sign of $\Delta$. In general words, the solution are given by $\dfrac{-e\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2d}$

- If $\Delta\lt0$, the solutions are complex numbers.
- If $\Delta\geq0$, the solutions are real numbers numbers.

In your case, $\Delta$ depends on $a$. Read wikipedia's link that I gave above to understand how to get the solutions.